# What purpose does the label form helper serve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What value does the label form helper add?

For example

```
<div class="field">
  <td><%= f.label :recipe_created %></td>
  <td><%= f.select(:recipe_created, [['Yes', true], ['No', false]], {:include_blank => 'Select'} )%></td>
</div>
```

What advantage does that have over the following other than scaffolding will automatically create the code above?

```
<div class="field">
  <td>Recipe Created</td>
  <td><%= f.select(:recipe_created, [['Yes', true], ['No', false]], {:include_blank => 'Select'} )%></td>
</div>
```

I was trying to bold the labels and thought there might be a way to define the label but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bold the labels via CSS using the 'font-weight:bold;' property. the label tags are useful to select/identify the field in an easy way.